# How to call variable as property object

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm currently on the middle of modifying a script, and I want to use `$variable_expessions` like they way object properties are used:

```
Function View-Diskspace {

##formating output
$TotalGB = @{Name="Capacity(GB)";expression={[math]::round(($_.Capacity/ 1073741824),2)}}
$FreeGB = @{Name="FreeSpace(GB)";expression={[math]::round(($_.FreeSpace / 1073741824),2)}}
$FreePerc = @{Name="Free(%)";expression={[math]::round(((($_.FreeSpace / 1073741824)/($_.Capacity / 1073741824)) * 100),0)}}
Write-Host "`nGetting disk volume info from $machinename..." -ForegroundColor Cyan;
$volumes = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_volume -ComputerName localhost

#i want to detect $FreePerc with less than/or equal to 15 percent and volumes with no capacity, such as disc drives
if ($volumes | Select-Object Label, $FreePerc, $TotalGB | Where {$_.$FreePerc -le 15 -and $_.$TotalGB -ne 0})
{
    Write-Host "`nVolume(s) about to reach full capacity:"
    $volumes | Select-Object SystemName, DriveLetter, Label, $TotalGB, $FreeGB, $FreePerc | Where {$_.$FreePerc -le 15 -and $_.$TotalGB -ne 0} | Format-List
    Write-Host "Please initiate drive volume clean up."
}
else
{
    Write-Host "`n##> All volumes have more than 15% of free space"
}


}
```

Comment: `$_.$FreePerc` - the property name isn't `$FreePerc`, it's `$_."Free(%)"` (and `Capacity(GB)`)

Comment: Thanks for your response. tried that, however it did not work. I even tried running using variable and property name to compare the result:

PS P:\> $volumes | Select-Object $FreePerc

Free(%)
-------
     87
     87
       
       



PS P:\> $volumes | Select-Object "free(%)"

free(%)
-------

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TessellatingHeckler's comment is right](https://stackoverflow.com/users/478656/tessellatingheckler). You are defining calculated properties right and executing them correctly however you are not calling your properties correctly.

If you ran `$volumes | Select-Object Label, $FreePerc, $TotalGB | Get-Member` you would see the properties you should be using. These are defined in your calculated property hashtable: "Capacity(GB)", "FreeSpace(GB)" and "Free(%)".

I simplified your function just to showcase the proper calling of the properties you were trying to interact with.

```
Function View-Diskspace {

    # Calculated properties
    $TotalGB = @{Name="Capacity(GB)";expression={[math]::round(($_.Capacity/ 1073741824),2)}}
    $FreeGB = @{Name="FreeSpace(GB)";expression={[math]::round(($_.FreeSpace / 1073741824),2)}}
    $FreePerc = @{Name="Free(%)";expression={[math]::round(((($_.FreeSpace / 1073741824)/($_.Capacity / 1073741824)) * 100),0)}}

    # Get WMI information and use calculated properties
    Get-WmiObject -Class win32_volume -ComputerName localhost | 
        Select-Object Label, $FreePerc, $TotalGB | 
        Where-Object {$_."Free(%)" -le 50 -and $_."Capacity(GB)" -ne 0} | 
        ForEach-Object -Begin {
            Write-Host "`nVolume(s) about to reach full capacity:"
        } -Process{
            $_
    }
}
```

Still using `Select-Object` the same way you were but then in the where clause I call the properties with their strings that you named.

If you *really* wanted to make your way work you would need to call the Name property of the hashtables. For instance....

```
Where-Object {$_.($FreePerc.Name) -le 50}
```

Comment: Thanks! I used the second option you provided.